# Customize directory destination for ES6 compiled files via Babel watcher in PhpStorm

Tags: ecmascript-6, phpstorm, webstorm, babeljs

I have a directory structure like below:

[image]

All **ES6** files are in the `js` directory. Now I want after compiling those files to put all of them into a `dist` directory but I do not know how can I do that.

I've added a **Babel** watcher in **PhpStorm** that has this configuration :

program :

```
D:\wamp\www\vuejs\node_modules\.bin\babel.cmd
```

Arguments :

```
$FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$ --out-dir dist --source-maps --presets env
```

Output path to refresh :

```
dist\$FileDirRelativeToProjectRoot$\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js:dist\$FileDirRelativeToProjectRoot$\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js.map
```

What changes should I make in the watcher configuration?

Comment: file watcher is set up to save files to `dist` directory. Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: yes, compiled files goes to a `dist` directory in the root directory , but I want go to a `dist` directory next to `js` that is contains source files

Comment: so, should it be `public/dist` rather than `dist`?

Answer (score 1):

It can look as follows:

```
Arguments : $FileName$ --out-dir $ProjectFileDir$\public\dist\$FileDirPathFromParent(js)$ --source-maps --presets env

Output path to refresh : $ProjectFileDir$\public\dist\$FileDirPathFromParent(js)$\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js:$ProjectFileDir$\public\dist\$FileDirPathFromParent(js)$\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js.map

Working directory: $FileDir$
```

Note that **Working directory:** field is usually hidden, you need to expand **Other Options:** to see it

Comment: For those wondering $FileDirPathFromParent(js)$ is the key here to rebuild the file tree correctly by capturing the path of the file from the js folder.